# QGIS sample raster via field calculator

Tags: qgis, sample

I'm trying to sample a raster by a point feature layer. I don't want to use the QGIS sample raster tool, since it creates a new layer/file everytime, which adds additional steps and unnecessary intermediate results, when doing this multiple times.

I want add the sampled raster values "in place", i.e. simply adding a column to the existing point feature layer/file.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved via the field calculator and the following expression:

`raster_value( 'choose_raster_layer_from_map_layers', 1, $geometry)`

This appends a column (output field name) with the sampled raster values.

[image: field calculator with example expression]
[image: raster value function documentation]