# QGIS use zonal raster statistics in Field calculator

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics

I want to "sample" a raster by a polygon feature layer, i.e. calculate zonal statistics (`'avg', 'min', 'max',` ...). I don't want to use the QGIS zonal statistics tool, since it's "append to layer" functionality doesn't work (see [How can I use the Zonal statistics "append to layer" functionality?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/465245/how-can-i-use-the-zonal-statistics-append-to-layer-functionality)) and therefore it creates a new layer/file everytime. This adds additional steps and unnecessary intermediate results, when doing this multiple times.

**I want to add the raster statistic "in place", i.e. simply adding a column to the existing polygon feature layer/file.** Is that possible, like it is for point features ([QGIS sample raster via field calculator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/469860/qgis-sample-raster-via-field-calculator))?

I tried the `raster_statistic()` functionality, however it always processes the complete raster (avg, min, max, ...), hence resulting in the same value for each polygon.

[image]

I also tried experimenting in the graphical modeler and I can avoid intermediate results when doing zonal statistics on multiple rasters, but I still can't solve the issue of appending to / overwriting the original file.

Comment: I'm not aware of a possibility to do that using expressions. I would advice you create a model for your workflow using the QGIS zonal statistics tool, so you just have to run the tool. Include a table join that joins the results of the output to the initial polygons, then delete the output layer.

Comment: that sounds reasonable, but all join tools that I know have the same problem as the zonal statistics... not appending to the original layer but creating a new output. Therefore I don't see a way to realize this in graphical modeler either, without creating a new file. Maybe this is an inconvenient safety design by choice to avoid accidentally destroying/modifying your original data... however it is inconvenient, always having to handle new files.

Comment: Yeah, but you can deleted the temporary outputs within the model so that running the model will rusult exactly in what you want, creating just the output you'd like.